# __init__ with ctypes Structure

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I don't know much about what is actually going on with `_fields_` and `__init__`, so I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but I'm trying to do the something like the following:

```
class Matrix(Structure):
    def __init__(self, dtype, nrow, ncol, data = []):
        self._fields_ = [("nrow", c_int), ("ncol", c_int)]
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.nrow = nrow
        self.ncol = ncol

        if dtype == float:
            self._fields_.append(("data", POINTER(c_double)))
            arr_type = c_double * (nrow * ncol)
            arr_inst = arr_type(*data)
            self.data = arr_inst
```

The goal is to call functions from a shared library I wrote in C that has the structure:

```
typedef struct DoubleMatrix DoubleMatrix;

struct DoubleMatrix {
    int nrow;
    int ncol;
    double *data;
};

void func1(DoubleMatrix *mat) {
// stuff
}
```

but it's not working. When I do:

```
m = DoubleMatrix(float, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4e74b99b208f> in <module>
----> 1 m = DoubleMatrix(float, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4])

TypeError: __init__() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

The reason I want to do this is because I will have matrices whose entries are of type other than `double`

---

---

**Edit**

I want to share what has worked but does not have my desired functionality:

```
from ctypes import * 
lib = CDLL("/usr/local/lib/ccalc/libccalc.so")

class DoubleMatrix(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nrow", c_int), 
                ("ncol", c_int),
                ("data", POINTER(c_double))]
    
    def __init__(self, nrow, ncol, data=[]):
        self.nrow = nrow
        self.ncol = ncol
        
        arr_type = c_double * (nrow * ncol)
        arr_inst = arr_type(*data)
        self.data = arr_inst
        
        return
```

---

---

---

**Second Edit**

I am sorry everyone, I think I didn't restart kernel of my jupyter notebook properly when probing this. Now the case is that python crashes with the following code:

```
class DoubleMatrix(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nrow", c_int), ("ncol", c_int)]
    
    def __init__(self, dtype, nrow, ncol, data=[]):
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.nrow = nrow
        self.ncol = ncol
        
        if dtype == float:
            self._fields_.append(("data", POINTER(c_double)))
            arr_type = c_double * (nrow * ncol)
            arr_inst = arr_type(*data)
            self.data = arr_inst
                
        
        return
```

Maybe This question should be closed/deleted so I can ask it properly? The heart of my question is still the same, how do I take my working code in the first edit, and add the functionality I mentioned. Again I am very sorry.

Comment: Could you share how you compiled the shared library?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I basically did `gcc -shared ./mylib.o -o libmylib.so`

Comment: *\_fields\_* should be class (not instance) wide.  And the member shouldn't be modified afterwards. I think you could easily get past your problem using a factory like method.

Comment: It would help to reorganize your question and state *in words* what you are trying to achieve along with your coding attempt (a [mcve] of the problem).